# Swift 3 RKObjectRequestOperation returns error unable to convert of type RKObjectRequestOperation

Tags: swift, xcode, restkit

I'm trying to convert code from an existing app to swift 3 (Xcode 8.1) but am stuck on the code below giving error:

```
cannot convert value of type (RKObjectRequestOperation!, RKMappingResult!) -> Void to expected argument type (RKObjectRequestOperation?, RKMappingResult?) -> Void!)
```

Here is my code:

```
class func getShoppingItemsForPage(_ page: Int,pageSize: Int,
                                       completionHandler:@escaping ([ShopItemModel]?,NSError?) -> ()) {

        RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath("search",
                    parameters: ["page" : page, "pagesize" : pageSize], success: { (request: RKObjectRequestOperation!, result: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in

                let resultArray = result.array() as? [ShopItemModel]
                completionHandler(resultArray,nil)

            }) { (request: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                completionHandler(nil,error)
        }
    }
```

I suspect this might be related to a similar error from FBSDKLoginManager where I am seeing

```
Cannot convert value of type (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, NSError!) -> Void to expected argument type "FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler!"
```

Here is the Facebook code producing the error.

```
loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: facebookReadPermissions, from: self, handler: {(result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!,error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                // Process Error
            }
            else if result.isCancelled {
                // Cancelled by User
            }
            else {
                let delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                delegate.showMainStoryboard()
            }
        })
```

Comment: this might help https://github.com/ekreative/testbuild-rocks-ios/blob/master/AppsV2/AVRequestHelper.swift

Answer (score 0):

```
class func getShoppingItemsForPage(_ page: Int,pageSize: Int,
                                      completionHandler:@escaping ([ShopItemModel]?,NSError?) -> ()) {

      RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath("search",
                                                       parameters: ["page" : page, "pagesize" : pageSize],
                                                       success: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, mappingResult: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in
                                                         let resultArray = mappingResult.array() as? [ShopItemModel]
                                                         completionHandler(resultArray,nil)
      }, failure: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
         completionHandler(nil,error)
      })
   }
```

Comment: This didn't work. There are 2 errors, if I change to the above, line 4 remains with the same error. If I change line 4 to have the question marks then the code you identified has the error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the error type from NSError to Error and make the call and result params optional.